# Player Disconnect Issue GKMatch and Gamekit

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center, cocos2d-x, gamekit

i am working with cocos2d game with GameKit. I am creating match with 2 player using GKMatch. All thing is working fine for me but When one player enters the background state or pressing home button , then player is disconnected. I want to run GKMatch instance in background also. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, after all "background" means the player stopped playing.

While the [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) might not mention that explicity, it does one thing, namely automatically logging in the player when the application enters foreground, which to me indicates there's simply no player GKMatch could be connected with while the app is in the background.

Comment: but how to keep alive this thing.....that is correct if player stops playing i want to keep alive that match. is it possible? See my app is still running in background. Can i have your email-id please?

Comment: I am using this example http://www.raywenderlich.com/page/22 for performing my task.

Comment: I'm sure the match continues for the other players, unless there's only one player left. Also, when the app goes in background, it may even lose internet connection. You can't keep a match open but you can resume a previously interrupted match if you handle that case.